# Creating a quiz that allows the user to select a topic and difficulty rating

Tags: python-3.x

so I would like to create a program consisting of a quiz that the user can choose from (3 topics) then, the user can select the difficulty of the quiz of the desired topic. For example, the user chooses Football (as the topic for the quiz) and Medium (for the difficulty of the quiz). I have gotten to the stage where the program asks the user for username/password but I do not know how to further continue my wishes to make this program.

```
print("Welcome to my quiz!")
print("Firstly, I am going to create a unique account for you so we can record 
your results!")

name = input("What is your name?: ")
age = input("How old are you?: ")

unique_username = (name[:3] + age)
print('"'+unique_username+'"' + " is your unique username for this quiz!" + " 
Please enter a password for your account ")
print("Password: ")
password = input()

print("Your password has been stored!\n")

print("What would you like to take a quiz on?"+" Football"+","+" Video 
Games"+" or"+" Capital Cities"+"?")
```

Comment: please share your code as text, not as image.

Comment: Woops, there u go

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your next step should be to ask the user which topic they want - so, first, you should create a list of available topics:

```
topicList = ["Football", "Video Games", "Capital Cities"]
```

then get the input, and see if it matches any of the items in the list:

```
if input in topicList:
    # Do Thing
```

If you would like to have topics contain multiple values - for example, the difficulty of the topic - consider using dictionaries.